# Target current dynamic element of each add

Tags: jquery

How to target the current id-result element for each row added ?

here is now i add the new row

```
function addFilterRow() {
  html = '<tr id="filter-row">';
  html += '  <td class="text-left">';
  html += '  <select id="company" name="company[]" class="form-control">';
  html += '  {% for company in damask_company %}';
  html += '  <option name="{{ company.filter_group_id }}" value="{{ company.filter_group_id }}">{{ company.name }}</option>';
  html += '  {% endfor %}';
  html += '  </select>';
  html += '</td>';
  html += '<td class="text-left" id="result"></td>';
  html += '</tr>';
  $('tbody').append(html);
}
```

here is how i try to append it

```
$(document).on('change', 'select#company', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var div = $('td#result', this);
    var id = $(this).val();
    var url = "index.php?route=catalog/product/getCat&user_token={{ user_token }}&filter_group_id=" + id;
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      success: function(data) {
        $(data).appendTo(div);
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can use common classes on the elements and DOM traversal to find the content related to the `select` which raised the `change` event. This has the added benefit of avoid the `id` conflict you're creating, as `id` have to be unique within the DOM.

Firstly amend all the `id` attributes to classes:

```
function addFilterRow() {
  html = '<tr class="filter-row">';
  html += '  <td class="text-left">';
  html += '    <select name="company[]" class="company form-control">';
  html += '      {% for company in damask_company %}';
  html += '        <option name="{{ company.filter_group_id }}" value="{{ company.filter_group_id }}">{{ company.name }}</option>';
  html += '      {% endfor %}';
  html += '    </select>';
  html += '  </td>';
  html += '  <td class="text-left result"></td>';
  html += '</tr>';
  $('tbody').append(html);
}
```

Now you can amend your event handler to retrieve the sibling `td`:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select.company', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $result = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.result');

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "index.php?route=catalog/product/getCat&user_token={{ user_token }}&filter_group_id=" + $(this).val(),
      success: function(data) {
        $result.append(data);
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: how can i do checkbox to check all in result
i tried something like this but checking all boxes in all results

$(document).on('change', 'select.company', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $result = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.result');

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "index.php?route=catalog/product/getCat&user_token={{ user_token }}&filter_group_id=" + $(this).val(),
      success: function(data) {
$result.append($('<p class="text-danger"><input type="checkbox" class="checkAll"> Select All</p>'));
        $result.append(data);
      }
    });
});

Comment: $(document).on('click', '.checkAll', function(){
            $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
        });

Comment: I'd start a new question about that. Code in comments is almost unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reset the old id="result" before appending the new id="result" by doing this

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      success: function(data) {
        $("#result").attr("id", ""); 
        $(data).appendTo(div);
      }
    });
```

This will remove the attribute ID result to "" empty and then your new id of result will start working. Otherwise it will select the first id of result always.

Comment: This won't affect any of the OPs logic, and even if it did, it would end up causing more problems than it solves.

Comment: No this will not create any other problem otherwise if you are still confused you can use the closest function to choose the closest item.

Comment: Read the question again. The OP is trying to retrieve an element by its id, not *remove* the id.

Comment: He is trying to get latest element by id.but he is getting old id again and again because ids are repeating by clonning the HTML. If he use my method, he will remove all old ids and the only one and last id will be remain left by which he can select the right element

Comment: That's not the case, as the OP has multiple elements with the same `id`, hence selecting by that `id` will only ever return the first one in the DOM. Even if this worked, it would be a bad idea. The best solution is to remove the duplicate ids entirely and work with classes properly, as the answer above does.